# TabControl shortcut key in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a tab control on my form. I would like to add a shortcut key for each page, so it could be used without a mouse or multiple tab key presses.

I can't find any property in controltabs properties to do this. I have tried to use the &-sign in the Text property of tabPage, but it doesn't work.

Comment: So what could be used without the mouse? Please add more details on what you are looking to do - this is too vague

Comment: You have three tags: vb.net, vb6 and vb6-migration. Do you want your answer in VB.NET or VB6.

Comment: Are you migrating to WinForms? WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabControl1.SelectTab(i)` in the `KeyDown` event of the `TabControl` to move from one page to another. I'm not sure how to get an underscore in the tabpage label.

You can also use a command box on each tab page to go from one page to the next.

Comment: if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
        && e.KeyChar != '.')

            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
   //  if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^[0-9]\d{0,11}(\.\d{1,2})?%?$"))
            if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"\.\d\d"))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            // only allow one decimal point 
            if (e.KeyChar == '.'
                && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

Answer (score 0):

Add code like this to your Form, then modify accordingly:

```
Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        Select Case keyData
            Case Keys.F1
                TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0
                Return True
            Case Keys.F2
                TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1
                Return True
            Case Keys.F3
                TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2
                Return True
        End Select

        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

End Class
```